# Add passport authentication in Angular2 + Express App

Tags: express, angular, passport.js

I'm trying to add passport authentication to my Angular2 app. I initialize that with **Angular-CLI** and **Express-Generator** npm package.

Within my  I created a `server` folder to include the express project generated by the **express-generator**.

Then I redirect the Express static middleware to the `dist` folder within my Angular2 root (generated by the `ng build` command).

I added the new `build` script as following:

```
"build": "ng build && DEBUG=server:* node ./bin/www"
```

But my question is related with **Passport** because it renders views using express, how can I do to integrate with Angular2 components?

I also add the next lines to my `app.js` file:

```
//Render the index within the dist path of Angular2
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/'))); 

// Catch all other routes using default index file
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});
```

One example of those **routes** is:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {

    res.render('login', { message: req.flash('loginMessage') });
});
```

How could I do to `render` this login through the Angular 2 components?

Comment: Were you able to find a way?  I'm looking for something similar :(